# iphone opengl es how to add an image as the background?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

this is a project  of opengl es, you can run it  on iphone sdk,

i want to know how to add an image as the background?

https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B8MGSbywP-HXY2YxYzk3YWItNzk3Zi00ZmNiLTk5NWYtOGY3NmU0OTRlYTM4

please give me source code.

Answer (score 1):

By drawing the picture as the very first thing (in form of a textured quad). Disable depth testing and depth writes.

#### Update: Code for some project

**Note: The actual code and structure strongly depends on the program in question!**

```
// one possible structure
void draw(draw)
{
    glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthMask(GL_FALSE);

    draw_background();

    glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);

    draw_rest_of_scene();
}
```

Comment: please give me source code, thank you very much.

Comment: @wertwer: I can't because I don't know your program. And there's no one size fits all solution for that, as it interferes with the rest of your code.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B8MGSbywP-HXY2YxYzk3YWItNzk3Zi00ZmNiLTk5NWYtOGY3NmU0OTRlYTM4   this is my program,  can you add any png image to the background ?   then give me your project  ,  or  show the detail of code that you added ?